# In a SQL Server how to change column data to a row wise format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server how to  change column data's as a row wise format?...

For ex:

Input

```
Name   date
--------------
xxx    12/12/2015
xxx    11/12/2015
xxx    10/12/2015
yyy    9/12/2015
```

Desired output:

```
Name  Date
------------------------------------------
xxx   10/12/2015  11/12/2015  12/12/2015
yyy   9/12/2015
```

Comment: So, you want a single date column with dates separated by two spaces in ascending order?

Comment: Normally you need to do this work on the client. In MySql, you can use the non-standard group_concat() method.

Comment: you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and dynamic pivot

Comment: yes, for specific name (ex: xxx) row wise only...

Comment: yes we already tried but which is defined columns, our requirement is name column and date itself, the result have to come single name and side by side date column value\

Comment: @marc_s the question is not duplicate of the given one as it is about simple aggregate concatenation .

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [name] CHAR(3)
   ,[date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([name], [date])
VALUES ('xxx', '12/12/2015')
      ,('xxx', '11/12/2015')
      ,('xxx', '10/12/2015')
      ,('yyy', '9/12/2015');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [name]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [name]
      ,STUFF
       (
            (
                SELECT ' ' + CAST([date] AS VARCHAR(12)) 
                FROM @DataSource
                WHERE DS.[name] = [name]
                ORDER BY [date] ASC
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
            ,1
            ,1
            ,''
        )
FROM DataSource DS;
```

[image]

Comment: Gotgn yes we got result from your query thank you very much for response...,   but we have table in DB so need to declare table, how to retrieve result from directly from table with select query statement

Comment: You can check this link - http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx in order to represent the date in different format.

Comment: @Ethirajram Do not declare new table, just replace the `@DataSource` with your real table name in the `WITH` clause and it will be fine.